# SnackBar still showing when I come back to previous Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-snackbar

I have a `SnackBar` in `Activity` A, if I click on a `Button` in `Activity` A I navigate to `Activity` B. If I press back immediately, I can see the `SnackBar` still being show in `Activity` A.

How to make `SnackBar` `dismiss` once user leaves the `Activity`.

My Effort:

Wrote a generic class which handles creation and dissmissal of SnackBar and

Create SnackBar :

```
public static Snackbar showSnackBar(View view, int text) {
    if(snackBar != null && snackBar.isShown()) {
        snackBar.setText(text);
    } else {
        snackBar = snackBar.make(view, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
    if (!AppRunningState.isApplicationBroughtToBackgrounds(App.get())) {
        snackBar.show();
    }
    return snackBar;
}
```

and in `onPause`:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SVSnackBar.dismissSnackBar();
}

public static void dismissSnackBar() {
    if (snackBar != null) {
        snackBar.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: use startActivityfor result. If its from B then you can hide snackbar

Comment: not in one case, I need a generic way to do it

Comment: who ever down voted, can you please state the reason ??

Comment: what to do with onShown and onDismissed ?? I want to dismiss it while moving away from an Activity. I don't want to get notified when it is dismissed. ready my question properly @AmitVaghela

Comment: added, please look at it

Answer (score 4):

Well ... normally you just use one Snackbar for one Activity/layout. So one way to do it could be writing a BaseActivity holding a reference to a Snackbar.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity { // use the one you want to extend

    private Snackbar snackbar;

    public void showSnackbar(View view, int textResId) {
        if (snackbar != null) {
            snackbar.dismiss();
        }
        snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, textResId, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (snackbar != null) {
            snackbar.dismiss();
        }
     }
}
```

Now always extend BaseActivity for every Activity you are using. It is basically the same thing you are doing but you do not need an extra class dealing with your Snackbar and you do not have to overwrite onPause() every time.

Comment: Are you saying that if you extend a BaseActivity the values set in runtime on it will be the same in all the next activities that you start which are extending BaseActivity? If yes, that's new for me. But I don't think you're right if you meant that.

Comment: If A and B extend BaseActivity, it doesn't matter if you instantiate snackbar in A, when you start B snackbar will be null. The condition "snackbar != null" will be always false.

Comment: A and B are unrelated to each other, that's right. Anyway, you should dismiss a snackbar before trying to show another. The problem is that you do not know whether you instantiated a snackbar before so you have to do the null check.
First time using BaseActivity#showSnackbar the check will be false. All other times using this method in the same activity the check will be true.

Answer (score 0):

Call `dismiss()` on the `Snackbar` when you start up the other activity.

Comment: cant do it every time I start a new Activity. I need a more generic way to write it once and happens all the time

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This should do the trick.

```
   snackbar = Snackbar.make(loginView, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        snackbar.setAction("Close", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                snackbar.dismiss();
            }
        });
        snackbar.show();
```

Here **setAction()** is optional. Need to use only if you want to close snackbar before the duration ends.

**EDIT:**

> The issue your facing might because your calling your **showSnackBar**
>   in **onCreate** method or within any of the methods that your calling
>   in **onCreate**. Its just an assumption since you haven't given the
>   entire code.